# datagridview data export to excel in vb net with save dialog

Tags: vb.net, railstutorial.org

I have used the below code and it was working 100% but I need to know how I can save in the save dialog.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sheetIndex As Integer
        Dim Ex As Object
        Dim Wb As Object
        Dim Ws As Object
        Ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Wb = Ex.workbooks.add

        ' Copy each DataTable as a new Sheet

        'On Error Resume Next
        Dim col, row As Integer
        ' Copy the DataTable to an object array
        Dim rawData(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

        ' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array

        For col = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            rawData(0, col) = DataGridView1.Columns(col).HeaderText.ToUpper

        Next

        For col = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            For row = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                rawData(row + 1, col) = DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value

            Next
        Next
        ' Calculate the final column letter
        Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
        finalColLetter = ExcelColName(DataGridView1.Columns.Count) 'Generate Excel Column Name (Column ID)


        sheetIndex += 1
        Ws = Wb.Worksheets(sheetIndex)
        'Ws.name = "Test10"
        Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, DataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1)

        Ws.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
        Ws = Nothing


        Wb.SaveAs("D:\5.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        Wb.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        Wb = Nothing
        ' Release the Application object
        Ex.Quit()
        Ex = Nothing
        ' Collect the unreferenced objects
        GC.Collect()
        MsgBox("Exported Successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
    Public Function ExcelColName(ByVal Col As Integer) As String
        If Col < 0 And Col > 256 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Argument", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Return Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
        Dim i As Int16
        Dim r As Int16
        Dim S As String
        If Col <= 26 Then
            S = Chr(Col + 64)
        Else
            r = Col Mod 26
            i = System.Math.Floor(Col / 26)
            If r = 0 Then
                r = 26
                i = i - 1
            End If
            S = Chr(i + 64) & Chr(r + 64)
        End If
        ExcelColName = S
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Your questions is kind of complicated to understand, could you please elaborate what exactly do you want when? Please also do not "just post the entire code" but only the portions which are actually necessary to understand your problem as well what you did already.

Answer (score 0):

If I got yout question, I guess you can handle this way:

```
Dim sfd As New Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
sfd.AddExtension = True
sfd.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"   
sfd.FileName = "D:\5.xlsx"
If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
   ... your code here ...
End If
```

So your code at the end will look like:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sfd As New Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    sfd.AddExtension = True
    sfd.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"   
    sfd.FileName = "D:\5.xlsx"
    If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
       Export(sfd.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Export(FileName as string)
    Dim sheetIndex As Integer
    Dim Ex As Object
    Dim Wb As Object
    Dim Ws As Object
    Ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Wb = Ex.workbooks.add

    ' Copy each DataTable as a new Sheet

    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim col, row As Integer
    ' Copy the DataTable to an object array
    Dim rawData(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

    ' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array

    For col = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        rawData(0, col) = DataGridView1.Columns(col).HeaderText.ToUpper

    Next

    For col = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        For row = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            rawData(row + 1, col) = DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value
        Next
    Next
    ' Calculate the final column letter
    Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
    finalColLetter = ExcelColName(DataGridView1.Columns.Count) 'Generate Excel Column Name (Column ID)


    sheetIndex += 1
    Ws = Wb.Worksheets(sheetIndex)
    'Ws.name = "Test10"
    Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, DataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1)

    Ws.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
    Ws = Nothing


    Wb.SaveAs(FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    Wb.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    Wb = Nothing
    ' Release the Application object
    Ex.Quit()
    Ex = Nothing
    ' Collect the unreferenced objects
    GC.Collect()
    MsgBox("Exported Successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub

Public Function ExcelColName(ByVal Col As Integer) As String
    If Col < 0 And Col > 256 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Argument", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim i As Int16
    Dim r As Int16
    Dim S As String
    If Col <= 26 Then
        S = Chr(Col + 64)
    Else
        r = Col Mod 26
        i = System.Math.Floor(Col / 26)
        If r = 0 Then
            r = 26
            i = i - 1
        End If
        S = Chr(i + 64) & Chr(r + 64)
    End If
    ExcelColName = S
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Dear Tell me the Complete Code which i paste my all code ?

Comment: I edited the previous post including what I would do.